# Window.location with variable path not working

Tags: javascript

This script gets the selection from a *comboBox*, and uses the selected values both to redirect to a specific path and to open a selected webpage.

```
function redirect(){
var obj = document.getElementById("cat");  // 
var obj2= document.getElementById("sub1");
var obj3= document.getElementById("sub2");
var redir2=obj2.options[obj2.selectedIndex].text.substring(0,4); 
var redir =obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text.substring(0,4); //
var redir3 =obj3.options[obj3.selectedIndex].text.replace(/ /g,"_");    

var url= redir+"/"+redir2+"/"+redir3+".php";
url=url.toLowerCase();

alert(url);

window.location.href = "np/categories/"+url;}
```

For some particular reason, while monitoring the log on firefox, sometimes it runs the path, sometimes it doesn't.

Either way, **it never loads the page selected**. (both testing path and page exist). Sometimes I get the green light on mozilla network console status, like this

GET
http://localhost/np/cat/auto/serv/testingpage.php    [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0 ms]

It never really loads the page. **How can i fix this ?**

Comment: what will be`url` looking like?

Comment: add some input samples

Comment: redirect() function should be call at some event.

Answer (score 0):

You could be having different relative paths and it might not work. 
*window.location.origin* gives you the full origin path such as for the current page: "http://stackoverflow.com".

So try this:

```
window.location.href = window.location.origin + "/np/categories/" + url;
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same result with this solution.
even tried window.location.pathname= "...." with the same result .

Comment: Run the command at the browser console and provide me the results.

Comment: Just tried this  " window.open( "/np/categories/" + url); " and it runs at it should, wich is , it opens in a new tab... but i would like  to load the new webpage on the same page...  so i guess the problem is not the path, ( the path is just fine ( checked when run window.open )

Comment: Ok. Could you also provide me the relative path?

Comment: I'm sorry bu i'm noob so i'm not following what's youre request.

One thing that's interesting is that if i insert the command Alert and put inside the code line window.location, it opens the popup window and then it loads the required url.Without the alert, it does nothing

the code that works: "alert(window.open("/np/categories/"+url , '_self'));
"

Any insights ?